# Select drop down list disappears after click when populating on demand

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, select

I'm populating my select list/drop on demand and for some reason the list disappears on MouseUp.

Code to populate the list:

```
<select id="UserList" name="UserList" onclick="getCountries()">.....</select> 
.
.
.
        function getCountries() {
        $.post("/Users/GetUsersJson/", { id: userId },
        function (result) {

            $.each(result, function (item) {
                $("#UserList").append(
                $("<option></option>").text(result[item].UserName).val(result[item].Id)
                );
            });

        }, "json");
    }
```

When I click on the list it gets populated just fine however when I release the mouse button it closes without letting me select anything on the list.
I can't figure out what's happening.

Any clues ?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the click event? Would it not be better to do it on load so that it's done automatically and only once? Or if it depends on a variable from a different part of the form, it would probably be better to call this when that other variable is changed.

Comment: That's the way I had it to begin with but was told to re-do it with the click event as the amount of data being loaded into that drop down menu "could slow down the page".

Comment: If you can, try mousedown instead and see if it works well. Also, you'll need a way of preventing it from loading everything again, or just clear the dropdown before repopulating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything that would cause your drop down list to disappear so I'd suggest putting in some alert boxes so you can determine precisely which line triggers the issue. That said, you should be aware that this is possible with the jquery each method.

```
function getCountries() {
    $.post("/Users/GetUsersJson/", { id: userId },
    function (result) {

        $.each(result, function (index, item) {
            $("#UserList").append(
            $("<option></option>").text(item.UserName).val(item.Id)
            );
        });

    }, "json");
}
```

Makes your code a little bit easier to read.

Comment: I set the list to load on that div Ajax load for now. I'll leave the question open for some time in hopes that someone will know what it could be.

Comment: Well I'd be happy to keep helping you out but what I was trying to say is that this code should function fine which means something else is wrong. I couldn't say what though without more information.

Comment: I can't even think of what else could possibly affect it....
The list appears inside of a modal JQuery .dialog() which is brought up upon Ajax.ActionLink() success: event.
Hmmmm....

Comment: Try creating a page with nothing but a button that triggers this function call and the drop down list. See if it still disappears.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="UserList" name="UserList"></select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('#UserList').click(function(e){
        if($(this).children().length == 0){
            $.post("/Users/GetUsersJson/", { id: userId },
            function (result) {

                $.each(result, function (item) {
                    $("#UserList").append("<option val='"+result[item].Id+"'>"+result[item].UserName+"</option>");
                });

            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Try the above:

The reason the popup disappears is because when you click the dropdown, it will make another GET request for the JSON data and re-populate your SELECT. I added a check for `children()` length, to make sure there are no `<option>` tags inside.